# Temperature-dependent pressure equilibrium constant of the heterogeneous water-gas shift reaction

Tags: equilibrium, reference-request

In the course of my research, it became necessary to perform thermodynamic calculations involving chemical reactions. One of the chemical reactions is the heterogeneous water-gas shift reaction

$$\ce{C(s) + H2O(g)<=> CO(g) + H2(g)}$$

and I need the temperature-dependent (pressure) equilibrium constant for my calculation. However, I could not find any information about it on the net or in the literature at hand. If anyone has an experimental or empirical equation, I would appreciate it if you could provide me with the source as well!

Comment: Look for standard formation ΔG, ΔH,  and ΔS and calculate the constant from it for given T. For more accurate calculations, you may involve molar heat capacities, as the above partly depend on T too.

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks for the edit and comments! I tried to find each value you provided but could not find the value for each temperature.

Comment: The point is, you need not to find it for each temperature.

Comment: @Poutnik My understanding is insufficient. How can I get the equilibrium constant?

Comment: this might help: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Equilibrium-constants-for-WGSR-Twigg-1989_tbl5_228506095 It does trigger on the keywords.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/154276/4945

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Thank you for your comment! I looked at the URL you provided, but could not understand the calculation procedure for my problem...

Comment: You may [edit] your question (as long as there is no answer) with any and all relevant details. What have you tried what have you read, where did you get stuck. Be precise and specific about your problem and other may help. I'm probably not the one, as I only searched superficially. This comment section is getting a bit chatty for its purpose, so better enhance the questions with the things you've learned.